# How to change wiring in outdoor electrical junctions filled with gel?

Tags: electrical, gardening

I moved into my current house 5 years ago and had a couple of outdoor connections fitted throughout the garden. I have never tried to do anything with them until now. As I open a junction box to add a new wiring I see this:

[image: gel filled junction box]

The box has a tiny hole, which I guess is where the gel was filled from.

I would like confirmation that I need to remove (very sticky) gel from the box, install a new connection and buy some gel to refill it. Is this the case?

Comment: Where in the world are you? This is certainly not normal practice anywhere I'm familiar with.

Comment: What do these boxes feed?  Landscape lights, sprinkler valves?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I am based in Germany.

Comment: @JACK They don't actually feed anything... yet. They were left by the builders at the end of a very long, thick cable in the garden so I could connect something to it later. 5 years later and I am trying to connect a Gardena Robot Lawn Mower base station and found this inside. No idea what it is or what to do with it.

Comment: Do you know where the other end connects to? What's the voltage?

Comment: The box seems to contain a 4-wire phone cable leading to an RJ-11 jack. Can you provide a picture of the cable feeding into the box? It appears to have been wrapped with yellow electrical tape as it entered the box - what's "upstream" of that? Is there a piece of beige phone cable heading in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something that used to be done for pool niche lights or landscaped fountains and ponds. This was a *non-conducting waterproofing gel* that was used to prevent corrosion and power leakage in wet location areas. It was usually applied in a time, post new GFCI and grounding requirements. I haven't seen it used in quite a while.

If you are trying to reuse the circuit in a newer application. You really need to verify that it is still active. Then you need to verify if the conductors and cabling are working properly.

Basically do everything necessary to upgrade the circuit to current wet location codes. Even if it means replacing the entire circuit. It is important to remember that you are dealing with a type of circuit that has a high potential for electric shock (electrocution). So it is important to follow the strictest protection codes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you cut the cable and install a new box then?

Comment: @PauloMatos certainly not before figuring out what is leading into the box and ensuring that the power to it is off! You may be in for quite a nasty surprise if you don't.

Comment: @FreeMan Sure - thanks for the tip.